# How would you implement auth0 with angular 17 SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, auth0, angular17

I recently tried to migrate my project to angular 17's new SSR. I was not able to figure out how to implement auth0-angular on both server (for the api, using JWT token) and client side (for authentication and HTTPInterceptor feature).

I wonder if one would have a fully working sample project? Or any track to follow to dig down the subject...

Thanks in advance.

I added the SSR feature with ng CLI. Then I followed various angular 16 tutorial and did my RTFM's, bu no luck on that side.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with SSR (Server-side rendering), but there's a good discussion of the issues here: [Authentication in Angular: Part V, Handling SSR](https://garage.sekrab.com/posts/authentication-in-angular-part-v-handling-ssr).  The linked blog post is recent and covers issues related to the standalone API which is the key difference in Angular 17.  (I recently read parts I - IV of the series which are relevant to non-SSR apps.)

Hope it's useful to you.